# Arjuna is gifted Chakshushi by a Gandharva

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, gandharva

Subsequent to their miraculous escape from the house of lac in Varnavat, the Pandavas along with their  mother Kunti ,roamed around/lived in the forests for a long period of time.
One day, Arjuna had a very fierce encounter with a Gandharva in the forest,whom he defeated using Celestial weapons.The Gandharva gave each of the Pandava brothers a hundred steeds, born in the country of the Gandharvas.The Gandharva also gifted Arjuna the unique science of Chakshushi.
What is Chakshushi?
What are the details of the story?

Comment: Chakshusi Vidya is related to Eyes it helps healing of eye if recited properly. It is somewhere in Chakshushopanishad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked especially about Chakshushi Vidya, I am quoting only those slokas relevant about Chakshushi Vidya from [Chaitraratha Parva of Adi Parva](https://ia800208.us.archive.org/21/items/mahabharata01ramauoft/mahabharata01ramauoft.pdf).

> चाक्षुषी नाम विद्येयं यां सोमाय ददौ मनुः । ददौ स विश्वावसवे मम
>   विश्वावसुर्ददौ ॥
>
> The vidya called Chakshushi was given by Manu to Soma. Soma gave it
>   Vishvavasu and Vishvavasu gave it to me.
>
> यच्चक्षुषा द्रष्टुमिच्छेत् त्रिषु लोकेषु किंचन । तत् पश्येद् यादृशं
>   चेच्छेत् तादृषं द्रष्टुमर्हति ॥
>
> One can see whatever one want in whatever form one wants in all three
>   worlds with this vidya.
>
> एकपादेन षण्मासान् स्थितो विद्यां लभेदिमाम् । अनुनेप्याम्यहं विद्यां
>   स्वयं तुभ्यं व्रतेऽकृते ॥
>
> This vidya is to be obtained by standing on one leg for six months
>   which I am giving to you without such necessity.
>
> अर्जुन उवाच - यदि प्रीतेन मे दत्तं संशये जीवितस्य वा । विद्या धनं
>   श्रुतं वापि न तद् गंधर्व रोचये॥
>
> Arjuna Said: O Gandharva, If you are giving this Vidya,wealth and
>   sastra even out of affection or fear of life, I will not accept such
>   gift.
>
> गंधर्व उवाच - संयोगो वै प्रीतिकरो महत्सु प्रतिदृश्यते । जीवितस्य
>   प्रदानेन प्रीतो विद्यां ददामि ते ॥
>
> त्वत्तोऽप्यहं ग्रहीक्ष्यामि अस्त्रमाग्नेयमुत्तमम् । तथैव योग्यं
>   बीभत्सो चिराय भरतर्षभ ॥
>
> Gandharva said: A meeting with Mahatma is ever a source of
>   gratification; besides you have given me my life. Gratified with you,
>   I will give you my Chakshushi Vidya. That the obligation, however, may
>   not all be on one side, I will take from you, O Beebhatsa, your
>   Agneyastra
>
> अर्जुन उवाच - त्वत्तोऽस्त्रेण वृणोभ्यश्वान् संयोगः शाश्वतोऽस्तु नौ ।
>   सखे तद् ब्रूहि गन्धर्व युष्मभ्यो यद् भयं भवेत् ॥
>
> Arjuna said: Okay, I will give you Agneyastra in exchange for the
>   horses and let our friendship live long.

If you want to know the whole story you can refer [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01173.htm). So Arjuna only accepted the horses but not Chakshushi Vidya offered by Gandharva.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No Arjuna never accepted the Chakshushi Vidya. That is for sure

Comment: @UdayKrishna Bharatarshabha is a name refering to anyone who is part of Bharata's Chandrawanshi Scion. If arjuna is the only Bharatawanshi/Kuruwanshi present there Bharatarshabha refers to him.